# Is there a typeable command to stop nodemon on a nix system?

Tags: node.js, unix, nodemon

Currently I hit **control C**, but I thought that since there was a command to restart **rs** that there would be a command to stop it all together.

I have tried

```
quit
exit
stop
```

and they did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact not a command to stop it.  Keep using Control C or if you really need that feature submit a request to the team on github.